# Multiple types on pasteboard including files, rtfd, and custom type (Mac OS X 10.6)

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop, nspasteboard

The new pasteboard api in 10.6 seems to work well once you get your head around UTIs, but I've come across a situation that I can't crack: What if you're declaring multiple data types in conjunction with a file drag?

See the way the new pasteboard works, you put data on it using setString, setData, setPropertyList, or writeObjects.  The first 3 require that you specify the UTI in advance so the receiver can select the representation it wants.

The last one - writeObjects - requires an array of NSPasteboardWriting compliant objects, such as the convenience class NSPasteboardItem.

The problem is that the Finder interprets any url added to the pasteboard as a literal url, so rather than dragging a file it creates a url to the file.

There is no way (that I can find) to create an NSPasteboardItem for a URL.  That leaves this (from the header):

```
APPKIT_EXTERN NSString *NSFilenamesPboardType; //Deprecated
// Use -writeObjects: to write file URLs to the pasteboard
```

However, if you mix a URL with an NSPasteboard item the result doesn't work.

```
NSPasteboardItem *noteItem = [[[NSPasteboardItem alloc] init] autorelease];
[noteItem setString:theString forType:NSPasteboardTypeString];

//Here is the problem: you can only have one or the other, not both.
[pasteboard writeObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:noteItem, nil]]; //A
[pasteboard writeObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObject:fileURL]]; //B
// A or B will work but not both
[pasteboard writeObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
fileURL, noteItem, nil]]; //Will not work
```

I would consider it a great example if someone could write something that would accomplish both of these together.

Here is the test:

- Drag to TextEdit should insert text
- Drag to Finder should add a file.

Comment: The last line of your sample: `[pasteboard writeObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
fileURL, arrayWithObjects:noteItem, nil]];` isn't even valid code (`arrayWithObjects:noteItem` in the middle of an argument list); is that a typo?

Comment: I’m facing the same question - did you ever find a solution @sg1?

Answer (score 2):

writeObjects: is not the only method.  You can also use:

- [setData:forType:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPasteboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSPasteboard/setData:forType:)
- [setPropertyList:forType:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPasteboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSPasteboard/setPropertyList:forType:)
- [setString:forType:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPasteboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSPasteboard/setString:forType:)

For `NSURL` you also have the opportunity to use the [NSURL Additions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000301-DontLinkElementID_3) (`+URLFromPasteboard:` and `-writeToPasteboard:`).

Comment: You NSURL link goes to a 404 page. Can you please fix the link or even better summarise what's there?